# Customizer: widget-synced triggers twice

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, customization, widgets, theme-customizer

I just noticed that `widget-synced` is triggered twice when you're trying to edit a widget, click on a text field, write something, triggers `widget-synced` once and after that, if you click anywhere else it triggers a second time.

[image]

Is this default behavior and can it be prevented in a custom widget?

Thanks!

Pinging @WestonRuter

Comment: I am asking because I have a some sortable text fields (using jQuery UI) in a custom widget and if I try doing the above, but instead of clicking outside the field I try to sort directly, the `Apply` button appears.

Comment: I kinda managed to fix it, don't know if it's the proper way, this is in case of sortable fields, using the `stop` event and checking if the "Apply" button is inside the widget: https://jsfiddle.net/6h5t5r6y/

Comment: Please add your fiddle as an answer to your question, then accept it, so we can close this question as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is that the widget will run its update logic on `keydown` *and* also on `change` for a given `input` element. See https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/4.7.2/src/wp-admin/js/customize-widgets.js#L891-L907

There are some tradeoffs made when widgets were added to the customizer to bring these PHP-driven interfaces into a JS-driven context. It wasn't perfect and so this is part of the reason behind the [JS Widgets](https://github.com/xwp/wp-js-widgets/) feature plugin, to modernize how custom widgets are implemented in the customizer.

If you want to really just listen for when a widget actually changes its state, you can listen for the control's underlying `setting` change instead. The setting will only be updated once after a given `keydown` and subsequent `change` event.

Answer (score 0):

I kinda managed to fix it, don't know if it's the proper way, this is in case of sortable fields, using the stop event and checking if the "Apply" button is inside the widget: https://jsfiddle.net/6h5t5r6y

Comment: Please add all the relevant code, with explanation, into your answer, as external links can get "cold". Thanks.